# Ansible- AWX login token API

Tags: api, ansible, yaml, devops, ansible-awx

I have installed Ansible-AWX and configured certain playbooks. I want to use the AWX API to run the ansible playbooks on a .net console application. However in order to do so I need a oauth token to login using the postman API. The problem is I am not able to generate the token. I have tried using the AWX cli and few other approaches still no positive results. 
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a shot here:

`curl -ku username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"description":"Tower CLI", "application":null, "scope":"write"}' http://<ip_address>/api/v2/users/1/personal_tokens/ | jq -r .token`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ansible/tower-cli/issues/478#issuecomment-370528556

```
$ curl -ku ryan:ryan -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"description":"Tower CLI", "application":null, "scope":"read"}' https://awx.example.org/api/v2/users/1/personal_tokens/ | python -m json.tool

{
    "application": null,
    "created": "2018-03-05T19:06:56.224538Z",
    "description": "Tower CLI",
    "expires": "2018-03-06T05:06:56.223889Z",
    "id": 4,
    "modified": "2018-03-05T19:06:56.234208Z",
    "refresh_token": null,
    "related": {
        "activity_stream": "/api/v2/tokens/4/activity_stream/",
        "user": "/api/v2/users/1/"
    },
    "scope": "read",
    "summary_fields": {
        "user": {
            "first_name": "",
            "id": 1,
            "last_name": "",
            "username": "ryan"
        }
    },
    "token": "ABy5N1fBiPujilEJjAUtmPlK8mTdGr",
    "type": "o_auth2_access_token",
    "url": "/api/v2/tokens/4/",
    "user": 1
}
```